# What are "termination points" and why do I need them on my electrical supply?

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution

An inspection of my electric supply service on the outside of my home in Maryland said I need 3 termination points and two grounding rods. The grounding rods I can get but I have no clue about these termination points. Can you explain?

Answer (score 8):

The termination points are where the utility attaches their wires to your system. You need 3 termination points because most US residences have 240/120 split phase service which is provided on three wires: two hots plus a neutral. The ground is of course provided by you via ground rods or (my favorite) a Ufer Ground (concrete enclosed grounding conductor).

Here is a photo of an overhead service termination.

[image]
<sup>Click for larger view</sup>

Comment: The mast would be considered the "*point of attachment*", not the "*termination point*". Typically a meter socket, or a junction box on the outside of the structure would be the "*termination point*". They may be satisfied if you install the mast and leave the feeder wires hanging loose, since they'll then have a place to connect the service. Though this would only be used in an overhead service drop, so may not be applicable in some situations. Communicating with the service provider to determine exactly what they want, is often the best course of action.

Comment: The splices in the picture are the termination points, not the mast.

Around here, your electrician runs feeder wires from the meter box to dangle from the mast as shown in the picture and the utility makes the splices just as shown.

Of course one should check with their local utility to determine their requirements, this was presented as an example.

Comment: I was just pointing out that not everybody is connected through an overhead service drop, and that asking the service provider is the best way to insure you've provided what they need.